# how to run the SQL statement in parallel via store procedure

Tags: db2

My Source file/(INSERT_TERRITORY_SQL3 table):

```
INSERT INTO TERR_CUST (select cnt from test a);

INSERT INTO TERR_CUST (select cnt from test a inner join test b on a.name=b.name;

INSERT INTO TERR_CUST (select cnt from test a inner join test b on a.name=b.name inner join test c on a.name=c.name);

INSERT INTO TERR_CUST (select cnt from test b);
```

like the above there is more than 50000+ statement are in file.

Running the below store procedure, which run the sql statement in sequential mode, Can you let me know how to run the SQL statement in parallel via store procedure.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TOP()

LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE fullname CLOB;

FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR 

SELECT SQL1 from INSERT_TERRITORY_SQL3

WHERE (TERRITORY_KEY<>'0' or TERRITORY_KEY is not null)

DO 

  SET fullname = v.SQL1; 

  PREPARE s1 FROM fullname;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE fullname;

END FOR;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

An SQL PL stored procedure will execute the statements in series.
You cannot change that.

You can invoke autonomous procedures, if you design for that.

Why do you think stored-procedures are connected with parallel execution ? 
That is normally an application layer problem.

At application-level , you can split up the script into chunks and submit those in parallel. The mechanism depends on the operating-system on which you want to invoke the scripts in parallel.

You become responsible for any concurrency issues caused by the parallelism, along with error checking and transaction-logging capacity issues.